# Request object is null - Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having a problem with a submitted form.

I create a form object in a controller method, and I specify that when submitted, it should be handled in another action method.

```
    $invoiceForm = $oldInvoiceForm ?? $this->createForm(InvoiceProjectInvoiceType::class, $invoiceProject, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('invoice_edit', ['id' => $invoiceProject->getId()]),
    ]);
```

Here's the invoice_edit route

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param InvoiceProject $invoiceProject
 * @return Response
 * @Route("/{id}/edit/invoice", name="invoice_edit", methods="POST")
 */
public function editInvoice(Request $request, InvoiceProject $invoiceProject){

    $form = $this->createForm(InvoiceProjectInvoiceType::class, $invoiceProject);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        $this->addFlash("notice", "La config a bien été créée");
        return $this->redirectToRoute('invoice_show', ['id' => $invoiceProject->getId()]);
    }
    else{
        return $this->forward("ClientBundle:InvoiceProject:show", [
            'id' => $invoiceProject->getId(),
            'oldInvoiceForm' => $form
        ]);
    }
}
```

I do get to that method but I get this error message:

Controller "ClientBundle\Controller\InvoiceProjectController::editInvoice()" requires that you provide a value for the "$request" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.

So I do a little test, I put "Request $request = null", to make it optional, and it goes through. Obviously it crashes later in the handleRequest part, but I wonder why the request Object isn't injected in the action...
Here's the html of rendered form (without the inputs because there are lots of them)

```
    <form name="clientbundle_invoiceproject_invoice" method="post" action="/client/131/edit/invoice">                
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Modifier les informations</button>
     </form>
```

Does anyone see anything unusual in the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you don't have include the `Request` class in your file header

```
<?php

namespace App\AppBundle\Controller;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

Comment: Different error message.  It would complain about typehints and missing namespaces and such.  I suspect something in the code is calling the action directly.

Comment: Wow, thanks... it is what my problem was, I had the BrowserKit import instead of this one. I didn't think to look there because other forms worked in that controller. The only difference between the forms that worked and those that didn't is that those who did were creation forms, and the others were editing forms. Do you maybe know why?

Comment: If the others form have the same Request attribute, I don't know why at all... It's strange... I never had the issue before...

Comment: For what it is worth, I tried BrowserKit with S4.1 and got " it references class "Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Request" but no such service exists."  Don't have a 3.4 app handy.  Interesting mystery.

Comment: Okay, I said something stupid. Actually, the forms that did work were handled in another controller (with the right import) but then forwarded to the one with the bad import, where no use of the Request object was made. So there's nothing weird after all, just a bad import. Thanks to you two for the help